# Socket.IO is triggering multiple 'on.connections' events after refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have implemented a basic comunication through websockets using Socket.IO. The problem is when the client refresh the browser and then initialize again the websocket this start to get duplicate messages. Also is incrementing by one each time that the browser is refreshed.

I take a look to the Socket object on the server and alwas says that there is only one client connected. It seems that the emit event or on.connection event is triggering multiple times.

Here is the code on the server:

### run.js

```
const http = require('http')
const serverSocket= require('./server')
const corsify = require('corsify')
const socketio = require('socket.io')

const cors = corsify({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8000',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
})

const handler = cors((req, res) => {
  if (req.url === '/') {
    // TODO: status message
    res.end('Service working properly!')
  } else {
    res.statusCode = 404
    res.end()
  }
})
const app = http.createServer(handler)

const io = socketio(app)

serverSocket(io)

app.listen(3455, () => console.log('listening 3455'))
```

### server.js

```
module.exports = function (io) {
  io.on('connection', socket => {
    var handshakeData = socket.request;    
    ns = handshakeData._query['ns']
    // create new namespace (or use previously created)
    var nsp = io.of(ns);
    nsp.on('connection', function (socket) {    
      socket.emit('message', 'hello!')

    });   
  })
  return io
}
```

### client.js

socket_uri and namespace are provided by myself, just ignore them.

```
var io = require('socket.io-client')
module.exports = {
    socket: null,
    init: function(){
        this.socket= io(socket_uri + '/' + namespace, { query: 'ns='+ namespace}); 
        this.socket.on('connect',  this.onOpen.bind(this));
        this.socket.on('disconnect', this.onClose.bind(this));
        this.socket.on('error', this.onError.bind(this));
        this.socket.on('message', this.onMessage.bind(this));               
    },
    onOpen: function(event) {       
        console.log(event)      

    },
    onClose: function(event) {      
        console.log(event)  
    },
    onError: function(event) {
        console.log(event)          
    },
    onMessage: function(payload) {  
        // onMessage is triggering one more time per each refresf.
        // Starting in one like normal, but then after refresh is 
        // showing up 2, 3, 4, 5... times
        console.log(payload)    
    },
};
```

Any help will be really apreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: just ran into the same issue.